# Onchange Event not firing EJS

Tags: javascript, ejs

I'm new on the EJS (Embedded JavaScript templating) and I'm trying to fire my `onChange` event of `dropdown` to load my other `dropdown` value.

My server side script (`index.js`) is where the function exists, and EJS is my client side where I want to fire my `onChange` event.

Its not firing my function, I've tried the following code:

Here is my `Index.Ejs` file:

```html
<select name="memberid" class="form-control" onchange="onchangeMember()">
  <% for (var i=0; i < memberlist.length; i++){ %>
    <option value=<%= memberlist[i].Id %>><%= memberlist[i].Name %></option>
  <% } %>
</select>
```

My `index.js` (the method that's not firing):

```html
var onchangeMember = function() {
  debugger;
  var selection = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log('here');
}
```

Comment: Where is your script in relation to your html?  Also open your developer tools (F12) and make sure there are no errors.

Comment: Ejs file is my html actualy..and there's no error on console..

Comment: So is your function variable declaration before or after the dropdown templating?

Comment: index.js is server side script and EJS file is client side..so i want to call my index.js function from Ejs on change event..thats it

Comment: i used the debugger to check the event firing...but its not firinig

Comment: So `index.js` is never included client side?  If so, that's your problem.  When you assign the `onchange` event handler, it's trying to call a function that does not exist at that time.  Put the event handler, `onchangeMember` in the script that _**is**_ included in the client side code and it should work fine.

Comment: So are there errors in the console when you try to make a change? when you inspect do you see the code?>

Comment: nope..its not firing my onchange event in Index.js

Answer (score -2):

You may have to give class-name to you select tag. After applying the class-name, your code look like:

```
<select name="memberid" class="form-control member_dropdown">
       <% for (var i=0; i < memberlist.length; i++){ %>
             <option value=<%= memberlist[i].Id %>><%= memberlist[i].Name %></option>
        <% } %>
</select>
```

Updated index.js file is looks like:

```
$(document).on('change','.member_dropdown', function()
{
    console.log("here");
});
```

I hope this will help for you.

Comment: i am not using Jquery